# Issue with DataflowRunner: Job stuck at 0%

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, langchain

I am working in a Jupyter notebook in GCP Dataflow and have issues using Dataflow Runner. I am trying to extract text from a website, chunk it, and create embeddings.
When using DirectRunner, the code runs as expected within a few seconds. With DataflowRunner, the job is stuck at 0%, the Dataflow logs only say " Executing Operation 'Create URL List' ". No error or anything else, nothing happens no matter how long I run it.

I am using a docker container image that is uploaded to Artifact Registry. In my pipeline, I am referring to that image. I am using Python 3.8 and Apache Beam 2.53.0.

I have tried the following:

- Different versions of Python and Beam
- Allowed HTTP and HTTPS traffic for compute engine associated with the Dataflow workbench (since the pipeline will need to access the internet)

Below is my pipeline:

```
def run():
    # pipeline options
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        runner='DataflowRunner',  
        project='my-project',
        job_name='knowledgebase-beam-v3',
        temp_location='gs://my-bucket/temp',
        region='europe-west3',
        use_public_ips=True
        
    )

    worker_options = pipeline_options.view_as(WorkerOptions)
    worker_options.sdk_container_image = 'europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/docker-repo/my-image:v3'

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        urls = p | "Create URL list" >> beam.Create(['link1.html', 'link2.html',..,'link_n.html'])

        fetched_contents = urls | "Fetch content" >> beam.ParDo(FetchContentFn())
        chunked_contents = fetched_contents | "Chunk content" >> beam.ParDo(ChunkContentFn(2048, 100))
        
        embeddings = chunked_contents | "Generate embeddings" >> beam.ParDo(
            GenerateEmbeddingsFn(project_id='my-project', location="europe-west3"))

        preview = embeddings | "Print preview" >> beam.ParDo(PrintPreviewFn())
```

I can show the custom DoFn's as well, but I believe it is not relevant for my problem since the job is stuck at the very first step, which is simply just beam.Create().
Any troubleshooting tips are also appreciated since the logs are not telling me much.

Thanks!